# Cannot iterate over a hashmap with structure "string": [list] C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, nested, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a hashmap that I created by asking an user output. I cannot print the second value of the hashmap which is a list of float numbers. Should I do a nested for loop? And if so, what is the code convention to do so?

```
/* 14. En una clase de 5 alumnos se han realizado tres exámenes
y se requiere determinar el número de:

a) Alumnos que aprobaron todos los exámenes.
b) Alumnos que aprobaron al menos un exámen. 
c) Alumnos que aprobaron únicamente el último exámen.

Realice un programa que permita la lectura de datos y
el cálculo de estadísticas 
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){

// Crear un mapa que guarde los valores 
// de los estudiantes en la siguiente forma:
// "estudiante": [nota1, nota2, nota3]

unordered_map<string, list<float>> boletin;
string nombre;
float nota_1, nota_2, nota_3;



for (int i = 1; i < 3; i ++){
    cout <<"Digite nombre del estudiante: " << i << endl;
    cin >> nombre; 
    cout <<"Digite las tres calificaciones: " << endl;
    cin >> nota_1 >> nota_2 >> nota_3;

    boletin.insert({nombre, {nota_1, nota_2, nota_3}});

}

// iterando e imprimiendo los elementos del 
// hashmap

for (auto i=boletin.begin(); i!= boletin.end(); i++){

    cout << i -> first << endl;

    cout << i -> second << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As the error message should tell you, there's no overloaded output operator `<<` for the `std::list` template. You have to iterate over the list yourself. The [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) should be very useful here (or for the list [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with an [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to use nested loop.
Code syntax should be like:

```
for (auto i=boletin.begin(); i!= boletin.end(); i++) {

        cout << i -> first << endl;
        list<float> mylist = i->second;
        for (auto it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << ' ' << *it;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful!